# Java passing BufferedReader, DataOutputStream and Sockets to a runnable thread class leads to socket exception upon writing to stream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, constructor, bufferedreader

I have two 'Client's, one 'Server' and potentially a 'ThreadManager' that implements runnable.

The two Clients connect with Server via TCP and partake in a protocol handshake/ authentication thing (successful), then I attempted to pass the existing BufferedReaders, DataOutputStreams and Sockets to 'ThreadManager' to manage threading messages between Client1 and Client2:

SERVER:

```
ThreadManager tManager = new ThreadManager(serviceToClient1,  inputStream, outputStream, serviceToClient2, inputStream2, outputStream2);
new Thread(tManager).start();
serviceToClient1.close();
serviceToClient2.close();
```

THREADMANAGER:

```
public ThreadManager(Socket cli1, BufferedReader inputStream, DataOutputStream outputStream, Socket cli2, BufferedReader inputStream2, DataOutputStream outputStream2)
{
this.cli1 = cli1;
this.inputStream = inputStream;
this.outputStream = outputStream;
this.cli2 = cli2;
this.inputStream2 = inputStream2;
this.outputStream2 = outputStream2;
}
```

this constructs successfully, however on `.start()` called from Server, debugging shows a "Socket Exception: Socket Closed" error as soon the following is called from within ThreadManager:

```
outputStream.writeBytes("NUMBER: " + i + "\n");
```

I'm not sure where the problem is created, would I need to close connections and recreate Sockets and streamreaders/writers from within ThreadManager? I tried only passing the Sockets in the ThreadManager constructor and then creating `new BufferedReader... etc.` but this seems to be just as bad. Could anyone suggest either the solution, or where the problem lies (or both!) :) thanks.

Comment: You close your `Socket` before you try to read from it on your `Thread`, so you get an exception. Either post more of your code, or try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your problem. Also, showing us the entire stack trace of the exception may be helpful.

Comment: Did you connect socket to remote end (via `accept` or `connect`)?

Comment: @Jeffrey - I think you've probably hit the nail on the head, yes, in Server I close the stream, school boy error. I'll post more code if that doesn't do the trick and note taken on the SSCCE :)

Victor - the client's connection is accepted (again, I'll make sure I post more code next time)

Thanks to you both.

Comment: OK thanks again @Jeffrey, I'm happy to mark any answer you might want to give as the answer since, well, you answered it! And more code next time, for sure. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ja_him Posted an answer for you to accept

Comment: @VictorSorokin What difference would that make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close your `Socket` before you try to read from it on your `Thread`, so you get an exception.